# Using AWS Data Pipeline to move data from AWS RDS to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, aws-data-pipeline

I was trying to move data from RDS to S3 as backup. I used DBeaver on my local pc to establish connection with AWS RDS and uploaded a csv file.

I, then, tried to create a datapipeline to send data from RDS to S3. Initially, I got an error `DBInstance not found.` However, when I provided region of DBInstance in "Edit Architect" as it is different from Data Pipeline's region, now, I don't get that error.

Instead, I get a different error; Error id: `ActivityFailed:SocketTimeoutException`

```
error message: connect timed out
errorStackTrace
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: Error copying record at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:65) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.runActivity(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:35) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.CopyActivity.runActivity(CopyActivity.java:22) at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. at private.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Unknown Source) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:192) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:177) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getRdsDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:161) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:73) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnectionWithCredentials(ConnectionFactory.java:301) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.createConnection(SqlDataNode.java:100) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getConnection(SqlDataNode.java:94) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.prepareStatement(SqlDataNode.java:162) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.open(SqlInputConnector.java:48) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.<init>(SqlInputConnector.java:25) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getInputConnector(SqlDataNode.java:79) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:47) ... 9 more Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2251) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806) at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
```

Could anyone guide me please where is the problem?

Regards